# Ubuntu is so SLOW

Tags: acer

I installed Ubuntu (12.4, I think) on my Acer Aspire One netbook because Win7 was so slow and I'd heard great things about Ubuntu.  Win7 was slow but Ubuntu is glacial, every program takes an age to load and every action is painfully slow.
What can be done to get it running at a decent speed?  I'm sure this is not how it is supposed to run.

Comment: Could you please add more details about your hardware? It may be an issue with a particular component (e.g. a missing graphic card driver), but we need to know at least what version of Aspire One you use.

Comment: Can you add information since your question does not say the type of hardware you have, what real version you did install (guessing does not help), how did you install it, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Acer Aspire is Listed in the "Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware"

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Acer/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Netbook

Please give detail of your model and hardware, and also if you are yousing WUBI ,VM or separate install

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my acer aspire one and it ran pretty good. Although there were problem with full screen flash and online games.

I have now switched to Lubuntu on my machine. Which is running very fast.

Comment: +1 for Lubuntu.  I installed Lubuntu 13.10 on my Acer Aspire One and it performs much better.  To get the correct graphics driver installed I also had to [do this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/getting-opengl-to-work-under-ubuntu#answer-27932) but now it even runs Minecraft at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't install the proprietary graphic driver.  Ubuntu offers a free driver for your graphics card, but free drivers cannot be 100% perfect because it is written by the open source community who don't necessarily have all of the information about the graphics controllers that the manufacturers do.

So first go to the Dash (the huge Ubuntu icon on the top-left corner) and search for "jockey".  After it finishes searching for drivers, find the graphics card driver(nVIDIA or ATI/AMD) and install it.  Reboot and Ubuntu should be much faster.